# xAxis values on both sides of Line Charts

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts, swiftcharts

I am using the iOS Charts library in my application. Charts are plotted correctly but the X axis values are shown on both sides in Line Charts. Is there any way to hide it or remove it ?

Comment: please provide some code related to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false` to hide `rightAxis` or replace with `leftAxis`

Comment: Thanks Tj3n.Your answer saved my day.Thanks a lot.